# How to resolve this video cannot be played error in video view?

Tags: android

I have tried almost every solution (bunch of different ways to write string path) available on internet. Tried other videos too but still I can't understand why this error is not resolving.
Someone please help me in this code.

I am using API 14.

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity
{
    Button button;
    VideoView videoV;
    MediaController mediaC;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_player);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        videoV = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        mediaC = new MediaController(this);
    }

    public void videoPlay(View v) 
    {

        String path = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video;
        Log.d("Pca", path);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        videoV.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoV.setMediaController(mediaC);
        mediaC.setAnchorView(videoV);
        videoV.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Do you have a log?

Comment: @der_Fidelis When i play my video, a dialog appears that says "Sorry, this video cannot be played."

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to run a video in android is using the `VideoView`. However, it only supports the following video encoding formats:

> H.263
>
> H.264 AVC
>
> MPEG-4 SP
>
> VP8

So if you try to play another format, it may display an error as it does in your case. So you can use a third party library like [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) or any other of your choice to play other formats.